# If clause classification confusion

Tags: sentence-construction, if

Although it is clear what it was meant here, I kindly ask you what type of an if sentence is this, and is not it supposed to be 'were/was' instead of 'is'?

> So whenever there is an outbreak, and to stress, these outbreaks have
> always tended to be very small, the health authorities do a pretty
> good job at stopping it before it can get out of hand.  **If one is to
> look** for any positive consequences of The Black Death, historians
> point to an increased sense of European unity, and a sense of shared
> human experience that brought people closer together.We have all gone
> through this together, it has affected young and old, men and women,
> rich and poor.

Comment: Where does this paragraph come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the confusion here is probably coming more from **one is to look** than from the if-clause. "be to do" or "is to do" phrases are a formal way of talking about the future or giving a command ([1](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/be-to-do-something)). For example:

> John and Jane **are to be** married this summer. (John and Jane are going to get married this summer) 
> You **are** not **to speak** a word of this to anyone. (Do not speak a word of this to anyone) 
> I **am** not **to be** trifled with! (I am not someone who people can mess with)

If we use the passive voice with this construction, then the result is similar to 'can' or 'will,' and is more usual of British English. For example:

> **Am** I **to be** sent to school against my will? (Will I be sent to school against my wishes) 
> This water **is to be** used for washing. (This water will/can be used for washing)

In the example you give, the phrase comes inside an if-clause. Just like how commands inside if-clauses are hypotheticals, this phrase introduces a hypothetical. **So, here, "If one is to look" can be replaced with "if one looks," or "if you look."**

Another possible source of confusion is the use of *one* here. In the quote you give, *one* is just a stand-in for "someone;" it is being used as a pronoun. The relevant [wiktionary sense](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/one#Pronoun) is

> 3. (indefinite personal pronoun) Any person (applying to people in general).

To answer your second question, **yes**, you can replace *is* with *were*; they are pretty much identical in meaning and connotation, maybe with the small difference that *if one were to do something* is more strongly hypothetical than *if one is to do something*.

It is also worth noting that the if-clause is somewhat of a non-sequitur: if one looks then historians will find? This ambiguity is the fault of the author.